# Signatures with Hybrid Encryption

Tags: authenticated-encryption

Typically, in public-key settings, sign-then-encrypt has been used to provide confidentiality and integrity. However, most public-key cryptosystems use hybrid encryption. I've been searching around online for best practices for signing data, but I haven't found any. How should signatures work in a hybrid cryptosystem? Do you sign after you encrypt the data and the symmetric key or before? All the literature is about public key cryptosystems and signatures but it's not clear this extends to hybrid cryptosystems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure sign-then-encrypt still works with hybrid and KEM/DEM public key encryption schemes. No need to change strategy here.

Comment: If sign-then-encrypt works generically with any public-key encryption scheme, then it will work with a hybrid encryption scheme since hybrid encryption is just one way to obtain public-key encryption.